# GraphQL - Get Product Variants Information - BigCommerce

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce

I'm new to GraphQL and looking for the correct syntax of the script to pull in product variations for a given product in BigCommerce.

Below query gives me the SKU for the product, but I would also like to return all variations SKU as well.

```
query {
    site {
        product(entityId:781) {
            sku
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

Have added below snippet to pull in the meta fields for variations but not sure if this is accurate as the results are blank

```
metafields(namespace:"App Namespace") {
                      edges {
                        cursor
                        node {
                          id
                          key
                          value
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
query getProductVariants {
  site {
    product(entityId: 781) {
      sku
      variants(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            sku
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To make things cleaner, you can abstract the product ID as a GraphQL variable:

```
query getProductVariants(
  $productId: Int
) {
  site {
    product(entityId: $productId) {
      sku
      variants(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            sku
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan makes sense. If I also needed to pull in a meta field for the variant what's the best way for that. Thanks for your help really appreciate it.